# Is the following differentiating under the integral sign correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, mathematical-physics

Suppose $$\frac{\delta f[u]}{\delta u(x)}\equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_x}+\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\right)^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_{xx}}+...$$
and $$f[u]=\int_\mathbf{R} \phi(u,u_x)dx$$
What then is $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\delta f[u]}{\delta u(x)}$$?

---

My guess would be

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int_\mathbf{R} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u_x}dx$$

Then $$\left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u_x}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$ Would that be right?

---

Anybody?

Comment: do you know the euler lagrange equation and first variation? by the way, you need to tell us something about $\phi$ so that we can answer your question. (Is it continuously differentiable?)

Comment: @Lipschitz: Firstly, thanks for commenting! Secondly, yes, $\phi$ is assumed to be smooth (generally well-behaved). Thirdly, yes, I have heard of the EL equations... but...?

Comment: @Lipschitz: Also I think since 
>$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} =\{u,H[u]\}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\delta H}{\delta u}$$ gives Hamilton's equations given that $H[u]$ is the Hamiltonian 

has been mentioned in class, I suppose they expect me to approach the question using that?

Answer (score 1):

Have been informed that I misunderstood the notation in my notes. The problem is resolved now! Sorry about that!